# Expo import error: invariant violation element type is invalid expected a string (for built in components)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm importing a component to my react native app and i keep getting the same error even after trying the solutions i already found online i am a beginner so it could be i'm missing something obvious

i tried wrapping my import name in curly braces but it didnt seem to help

```
my main app.js
    import React from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, View, Header, } from 'react-native';
    import { NumberInput } from './src/components/NumberInput';

    export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container} >
        <Header>Efees</Header>
          <NumberInput />
        </View>
      );
    }
    }


    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      },
      TextInputStyle: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        height: 40,
        borderRadius: 10,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: '#009688',
        marginBottom: 10,
        width: 100,
        fontSize: 20
    }
    });


    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';

    export default class NumberInput extends Component {

    render() {
      return (
          <TextInput
                    underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                    style={styles.TextInputStyle}
                    keyboardType={'numeric'}
          />
      );
     }
    }


    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      TextInputStyle: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        height: 40,
        borderRadius: 10,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: '#009688',
        marginBottom: 10,
        width: 100,
        fontSize: 20
    }
    });
```

expo is giving me this error message:

> 

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

This error is located at:
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at App.js:8)
    in App (at withExpoRoot.js:20)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at withExpoRoot.js:19)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:35)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're importing your NumberInput component wrong. You're exporting it as default, but importing it as a named export.

To fix this, change the 3rd line of main.js to this:

```
import NumberInput from './src/components/NumberInput';
```

and that should work.

This is because we have

Named Export: (export)
With named exports, one can have multiple named exports per file. Then import the specific exports they want to be surrounded in braces. The name of the imported module has to be the same as the name of the exported module.

Default Export: (export default)
One can have only one default export per file. When we import we have to specify a name and import like:

```
import NumberInput from './src/components/NumberInput';
```

So named export is imported with curly braces and default is without curly braces.

Moreover, we can import all named export as :

```
import * as NamedNumberInput from "./src/components/NamedNumberInput";
```

Comment: i did that and the error is still there i changed the third line of main js should i also change how im exporting the component?

Comment: Can you tell me which version of react-native are you using? Open App.js file and modify this line
`class YourApp extends Component {`
into
`export default class YourApp extends Component<{}> {`

Comment: im running react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.59.8

Comment: should i update the line from my app.js file or from my component file NumberInput.js ?